# Get number of milliseconds for a localised date, taking into account daylight savings

Tags: datetime, google-bigquery, dst

I have data in Google BigQuery that looks like this:

---

```
sample_date_time_UTC     time_zone       milliseconds_between_samples
--------                 ---------       ----------------------------
2019-03-31 01:06:03 UTC  Europe/Paris    60000
2019-03-31 01:16:03 UTC  Europe/Paris    60000
...
```

Data samples are expected at regular intervals, indicated by the value of the `milliseconds_between_samples` field:

The `time_zone` is a string that represents a Google Cloud [Supported Timezone Value](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Supported-Time-Zone-Values_66194188)

---

I'm then checking the ratio of the actual number of samples compared to the expected number over any particular day, for any single day range (expressed as a local date, for the given `time_zone`):

```
with data as 
  ( 
    select 
      -- convert sample_date_time_UTC to equivalent local datetime for the timezone
      DATETIME(sample_date_time_UTC,time_zone) as localised_sample_date_time, 
      milliseconds_between_samples 
    from  `mytable` 
    where sample_date_time between '2019-03-31 00:00:00.000000+01:00' and '2019-04-01 00:00:00.000000+02:00'
  ) 

select date(localised_sample_date_time) as localised_date, count(*)/(86400000/avg(milliseconds_between_samples)) as ratio_of_daily_sample_count_to_expected 
from data 
group by localised_date 
order by localised_date
```

The problem is that this has a bug, as I've hardcoded the expected number of milliseconds in a day to `86400000`. This is incorrect, as when daylight saving begins in the specified `time_zone` (`Europe/Paris`), a day is 1hr shorter. When daylight saving ends, the day is 1hr longer.

So, the query above is incorrect. It queries data for 31st March of this year in the `Europe/Paris` timezone (which is when daylight saving started in that timezone). The milliseconds in that day should be `82800000`.

Within the query, how can I get the correct number of milliseconds for the specified `localised_date`?

**Update:**

I tried doing this to see what it returns:

```
select DATETIME_DIFF(DATETIME('2019-04-01 00:00:00.000000+02:00', 'Europe/Paris'), DATETIME('2019-03-31 00:00:00.000000+01:00', 'Europe/Paris'), MILLISECOND)
```

That didn't work - I get `86400000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Juta, for the hint on using UTC times for the calculation. As I'm grouping my data for each day by a localised date, I figured out that I can work out milliseconds for each day by getting the beginning and end datetime (in UTC), for my 'localised' date, using the following logic:

```
-- get UTC start datetime for localised date
-- get UTC end datetime for localised date

-- this then gives the milliseconds for that localised date:
datetime_diff(utc_end_datetime, utc_start_datetime, MILLISECOND);
```

So, my full query becomes:

```
with daily_sample_count as (
  with data as 
    ( 
      select 
        -- get the date in the local timezone, for sample_date_time_UTC
        DATE(sample_date_time_UTC,time_zone) as localised_date, 
        milliseconds_between_samples 
      from  `mytable` 
      where sample_date_time between '2019-03-31 00:00:00.000000+01:00' and '2019-04-01 00:00:00.000000+02:00'
    ) 

  select
    localised_date,
    count(*) as daily_record_count,
    avg(milliseconds_between_samples) as daily_avg_millis_between_samples,
    datetime(timestamp(localised_date, time_zone)) as utc_start_datetime,
    datetime(timestamp(date_add(localised_date, interval 1 day), time_zone)) as utc_end_datetime
  from data 
)

select
  localised_date,
  -- apply calculation for ratio_of_daily_sample_count_to_expected
  -- based on the actual vs expected number of samples for the day
  -- no. of milliseconds in the day changes, when transitioning in/out of daylight saving - so we calculate milliseconds in the day
  daily_record_count/(datetime_diff(utc_end_datetime, utc_start_datetime, MILLISECOND)/daily_avg_millis_between_samples) as ratio_of_daily_sample_count_to_expected
from
  daily_sample_count
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the difference in milliseconds for the two timestamps by removing the `+01:00` and `+02:00`. Note that this gives the difference between the timestamps in UTC: `90000000`, which is not the same as the actual milliseconds that passed.

You can do something like this to get the milliseconds for one day:

```
select 86400000 + (86400000 - DATETIME_DIFF(DATETIME('2019-04-01 00:00:00.000000', 'Europe/Paris'), DATETIME('2019-03-31 00:00:00.000000', 'Europe/Paris'), MILLISECOND))
```